Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
I am getting following error when my function app starts and tries to trigger on a queue message:

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.AddOrUpdate'. System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Azure.Storage.Queues: Settings must be of the form "name=value".

Everything works perfectly locally.
My Azure Function is running newest isolated mode.
This is my function:
[Function(nameof(VesselAddOrUpdate))]
public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("update-or-add-vessel", Connection = "QueueConnection")] QueueMessage vesselJson)
{
        var vessel = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Vessel>(vesselJson.Body);

    Dictionary<string, object> props = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "service", "xx.update.or.add.vessel.job" }, { "vesselName", vessel.VesselName } };

    using (_logger.BeginScope(props))
    {
        var service = new XXServiceAddOrUpdateService(vessel, _repo, _config);
        await ServiceExecutor.RunAsync(service, _logger, false);
    }
}

Here is my settings:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "Q88NotifyCron": "0 0 3 * * WED",
    "Q88Cron": "0 0 7,12,17 * * *",
    "QueueConnection__queueServiceUri": "https://xxx.queue.core.windows.net"
  }
}

Web Job Nuget:


Any pointers what this could be?

In portal, you need to given values of connection string not just the queue url. The code which worked for me:
local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "rithcon": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwik3;AccountKey=dfMGknEk30g3c3Q==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}

In your code you should not use QueueConnection__queueServiceUri this but should use  QueueConnection
Function1.cs:
using System;
using Azure.Storage.Queues.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp174
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("testqueue", Connection = "rithcon")] QueueMessage message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {message.MessageText}");
        }
    }
}

csproj packages:
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.18.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  

Then deployed to Azure Function App.
Make sure the connection string exists:

If does not exist make sure to create it.
Output:
Sending message:

Function got triggered:

